# On the number of strict minimum points of an extended real-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am stuck in the following question:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $x,y\in X$ such that $x\ne y$. Let $\varphi:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\bigcup\{\infty\}$. Let $Z$ be the set of the points $z\in]x,y[:=\{\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y:\lambda\in (0,1)\}$ such that there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $z$ such that
$$
\varphi(u)>\varphi(z)\quad \forall u\in (V\bigcap]x,y[)\setminus\{z\},
$$
Prove that $Z$ is a countable set.

Comment: I don't have answer but ,considering that ]x,y[ is homeomorphic to a bounded open real interval, an equivalent Q would be the case $X=R$

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, it suffices to consider the case where $X$ is the reals.For each $p$ in the set you denote as $Z$, let $f(p)\in Q^+$ where $$\forall r\in ]x,y[\cap ]-f(p)+p,f(p)+p[ (r\ne p\to \psi (r)<\psi (p)).$$By contradiction,suppose $Z$ is uncountable. Let $q_0\in Q^+$ such that $f^{-1}\{q_0\}=\{p\in Z :f(p)=q_0\}$ is uncountable. Such  a $q_0$ exists because $Z=\cup_{q\in Q^+}f^{-1}\{q\}$ is uncountable, and $Q^+$ is countable. Now if $p_1,p_2$ are distinct members of $f^{-1}\{q_0\}$ then $|p_1-p_2|\geq q_0$ by the def'n of $f$, hence $$]p_1-q_0/2,p_1+q_0/2[\cap ]p_2-q_0/2,p_2+q_0/2[=\phi.$$ So for each $p\in f^{-1}\{q_0\}$ choose $$g(p)\in ]p-q_0/2,p+q_0/2[\cap Q.$$ Then $g$ is a one-to-one function from the uncountable set $f^{-1}\{q_0\}$ into $Q$, which is impossible.